# Restrict published port to a specific container with Docker

Tags: docker, port

I have two Docker images :

- a tomcat image, exposing the port 8080
- a mysql image, exposing the port 3306

I run two containers using these images, linking mysql with tomcat :

```
docker run -itd -p 3306:3306 --name mysql mysql
docker run -itd -p 8080:8080 --link mysql:mysql --name tomcat tomcat
```

When I do that, tomcat communication with mysql works fine, and my tomcat and mysql containers are available on the server host, respectively on ports 8080 and 3306.

Now I would like the port 3306 to be closed on the server host and only available for the tomcat container. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case you can simply skip the `-p` parameter like:

```
docker run -itd --name mysql mysql
docker run -itd -p 8080:8080 --link mysql:mysql --name tomcat tomcat
```